# How to trace SQL statements for a specific table?

Tags: sql, triggers, db2, trace, db2-luw

I'm currently working with DB2 v10.5 and I need to log all SQL Statements that occurr on a specific table (A). For instance, if an INSERT occur on table A, I need to "grab" that SQL Statement and log it into another table (A_LOGGER).

The solution I've reached was to create a TRIGGER (for each CRUD operation) over table A that looks into the table `SYSIBMADM.SNAPDYN_SQL` and try to save the last executed statement on table A.

Example for the `INSERT` Statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER OPERATIONS_INSERT_TRIGGER 
AFTER INSERT ON REPLDEMO.OPERATIONS
REFERENCING NEW AS OBJ
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
INSERT INTO REPLDEMO.OPERATIONS_LOGGER (LAST_SQL_STATEMENT)
SELECT STMT_TEXT FROM SYSIBMADM.SNAPDYN_SQL
WHERE 1=1
AND STMT_TEXT LIKE 'INSERT INTO REPLDEMO.OPERATIONS (%'
AND STMT_TEXT NOT LIKE '%?%';
END%
```

But looking at table `SYSIBMADM.SNAPDYN_SQL` is not the best solution because you cannot guarantee that you'll get the truly last SQL Statement executed on table A. Moreover, if there's a massive number of sql statements executed over table A in a very short period the TRIGGER will replicate many of the statements already saved on A_LOGGER.

So, my question is: Is there an effective and secure way to get the last SQL Statement executed over a table?

Thanks.

Comment: I think a better way of accomplishing this would be to [set up audit](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0050525.html) of that table.

Comment: Oh ok @mustaccio... I was hoping that it would exist a SYS table with that info... I was looking for a easier solution.
Thank you!